# SelectIndexChanged Combobox event won't fire when items list is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

In my code I have combobox and I bound it by bindingData control.. And I used selectIndexChanged to do some code for each active item in the combobox..

My problem is in this case:
My bindingData is empty (so combobox index =-1) then I add item "item1" to my bindingData (active combobox item is "item1") but SelectIndexChanged is not firing. Why?

the code:

```
   //first combobox is empty
        myBindingSource.DataSource = null;
        comboBox_Choixpiece.DataSource = myBindingSource;

   //then combobox Contains 1 item but SelectIndexChanged event is not firing !!
        myBindingSource.DataSource = someSource;
        comboBox_Choixpiece.DataSource = myBindingSource;
```

please help me

Comment: Often nothing is selected even when the data is filled...

Comment: No.. item added is displayed in combobox

Comment: displayed doesnt make it selected

Comment: displayed and selected

Comment: you havent showned how/when the method is connected to the listbox.

Comment: SelectedIndex event will be fired if the index changes and since you have only one item the index isn't changing it always stays 0. So add probably one more item and trying changing the displayed item (index) and your event should fire up

Comment: But it's changed from -1 to 0

Comment: @user3544324 No you got that wrong. SelectedIndexChanged event is fired only when you change the displayed item on the combobox either mechanically or programmatically. Adding a new item to your combobox doesn't mean you're changing any index. If you want to run a set of code when you add new items you could probably use DatasourceChanged event since you're binding the data this should help you.